# Converging Iteration with an Equation and a Table

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I had this assignment question with the following equation:

$$1177.36952x = (0.057240 \cdot T^3)^{0.5}$$

and the question was to solve for temperature. However $x$ is dependent on T so an iteration was required. We also had a table that listed values for $T\cdot (1/135.7571)$ and $x$. The solution was to guess $T=300\ K$, find $x$ by interpolating then use the formula for the new $T$, which converges at around $297.4\ K$. I tried the reverse, guess $T= 300\ K$ and use the formula to find $x$ and the table to find $T$, but my temperature values seem to diverge.

Is it possible that solving for 1 variable can converge while the other diverges for this technique? If it is, how can I tell which will converge? Thanks a lot.

Some of the table values.------------------------------------
2.6---------2.7---------2.00-------2.10------2.20--------2.30------(T*(1/135.7571)--------------
0.9878---0.9770------1.075------1.057-------1.041---------1.026------x--------------------------

I think my question will be more clear if I post my values. If I guess $T = 300$, then solving for x I get ~ 1.05558 and using the table $T\cdot (1/135.7571)$ = 2.1069 and T = 286.0317 K. If I sub this value in, I get $x = 0.9830108$ and $T = 358.982 K$, if I sub in this value the temperature falls below 200 K outside my table. Yet if do it the other way around the answer quickly converges.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't think I was very clear. Perhaps I should edit my post.

Comment: You should be able to self-delete your Question, provided it has no upvoted or accepted Answer.   If you cannot find the link below the Question, an alternative is to flag the Question for moderator attention.  The defacing of Questions, even your own, is considered poor practice.